# Border around Mega Drop Down

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, border

I am building a CSS only drop down list. I need to have a continuous border around the `<li>` in the main navigation list as well as the nested `<ul>` that is the submenu that appears on hover.

Currently I am trying to eliminate the top border where the sub-menu and top nav bar meet by positioning the `<ul>` underneath `<li>` using the z-index property. The `<li>` has relative positioning attached to it and the `<ul>` submenu is positioned in relation to that (I realize that z-index only works on a positioned element.) Z-index appears to be working, but the border continues to show through.

You can see a sample [here](http://www.malcolmmcatee.com/weavers/)

Comment: "using the z-index property. The" answer needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

the element that you are trying to hide (ul) is a direct descendant of the one that has to be on top (li). That can't be done with the z-index. (and the z-index of the ancestor is irrelevant)

You would need to place another element, child of the li, to hide the part of the border that you don't want

That is, if you have a father and 2 childs, first goes the father and then the child that has the lower z-index. z-index giver preference between the brothers, but not to the son in front of the father.